# How to bundle GLSL files with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, glsl, webgl

I'm working on a WebGL project that requires custom `.glsl` shaders. The project bundles the app with Gulp, so I'm trying to use https://github.com/mikecao/gulp-glsl which is a "Gulp plugin that converts GLSL code into minified strings." Perfect!

I ran `npm install gulp-glsl --save-dev` and my `gulpfile.js` looks as follows:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const glsl = require('gulp-glsl');

gulp.src('**/GLSL/*.glsl')
    .pipe(glsl({format: 'raw'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

And then I try to import my shader like this:

`import fragShader from "./GLSL/frag.glsl";`

But the Gulp compiler gives me a Compile Error:

```
[13:27:17] gulp-notify: [Compile Error]
/Users/.../WebGL/GLSL/polyFrag.glsl:1
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
^
ParseError: Unexpected character '#'
```

I don't need Gulp to compile the `.glsl` file, I just need it to turn it into a string for use with WebGL. What can I do with Gulp to make this happen?

Comment: By "turn it into a string", do you mean "minify" the glsl result ?

Comment: @DacreDenny The problem is that Gulp is treating `#extension GL_OES` as JavaScript, which it doesn't understand. I need to convert the `.glsl` file to a string, so it would be the equivalent to `var fragShader = "#extension GL_OES : enable"`. Webpack and Rollup can handle this easily, but I can't seem to get it working with Gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp is a task runner. It doesn't bundle you scripts, but can launch some other tool to bundle or preprocess.
It looks like your issue is related to the way you import shader and not to minifier module.

`ParseError` fails on valid glsl shader directive.

I suggest trying to import your `.glsl` without `gulp-glsl` first.
If your project uses some bundler like browserify or webpack - check for glsl-importer module for that bundler (for example `webpack-glsl-loader` for webpack).

Comment: Then what does https://github.com/mikecao/gulp-glsl do? It claims to be a "Gulp plugin that converts GLSL code into minified strings."

Comment: And writes those back to filesystem to `build` directory in readme example (`.pipe(gulp.dest('build'))`). That is changing one .glsl file to another .glsl file (minified). Old files content can be treated as string as well.

Comment: Shader file content is just a plain text without any magic. `gulp-glsl` doesn't seem to be helpful in context of bundling.

Comment: Thanks! I did misunderstand what Gulp was doing, but the project is using Browserify, so I was able to get it working with https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-shader

Answer (score 0):

Did you know about [glslify](https://github.com/glslify/glslify)?

is a Node.js-style module build system, much like
browserify, except for GLSL shaders! It allows you to share
and consume shader code on npm.

It forms one of the core components of the [stack.gl](https://github.com/stackgl) ecosystem, allowing you to install GLSL modules from npm and use them in your shaders. This makes it trivial to piece together different effects and techniques from the community, including but certainly not limited to fog, noise, film grain, raymarching helpers, easing functions and lighting models.

Because glslify just outputs a single shader file as a string, it's easy to use it with any WebGL framework of your choosing, provided they accept custom shaders.